# GWT menu item text alignments issues

Tags: gwt

Is it possible in GWT to set Menu Item text in two different alignments,what I mean to say is
I want my menu item's label to be left justified and its accelerator key to be right justified.

i.e,

```
      Create     Alt+Ctrl+C 
      Edit          Shift+E
      Optimize       Ctrl+O
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a "boolean asHTML" option when creating menu items, set that to true, then use CSS to left align and right align the text you want to align.

See the docs: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuItem.html

Comment: hi,
Thanks for the reply.
Can I have the line of code please.Actually I am not that proficient in using CSS, I use the getElement().getStyle() to do any changes whenever needed...
Could you please explain it little more.
Many Thanks

Comment: Are you building the UI using ui:binder in XML or doing it the old fashioned way using pure java code?